# Work Project - Setting buffered reader String to another string

Tags: java

Yesterday I had a question and had a prompt and helpful answer regarding a project I am doing at work, so today I thought I would try my luck again with another problem I am having.

My project is to take a "ACH" file (simply a fixed-format text file) using a GUI, process it, re-format the data (some things copied once, some more than once, some not at all), and finally export to a new .ACH file.

I should begin by giving an example of the type of file I will be working with, this is just an example since I can't post a real ACH file online.

```
111111111111111111111111
522293884838383848484838483884
62837717273727
62993304993918
621272773727755828
821200303299191
90000000000000000000000000
99999999999999999999999999
99999999999999999999999999
```

The "processing" requires me to "batch" the data above in a format where I place it in "clusters" of 5-6-8 with the "5" and "8" number being the same for each cluster and using each six on the list, for example:

```
522293884838383848484838483884
62837717273727
821200303299191

522293884838383848484838483884
62993304993918
821200303299191

//and so on
```

I have created a program that allows me to (almost) achieve this yet I have run into one problem - a "nullpointerexception". Before I begin to explain further my issue allow me to post my code:

```
package nacha;

import java.io.*;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;



public class Nacha extends JComponent implements Accessible

{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        String five = null;
        String eight = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;             //Counter variables for the numbers that should only 
        int count3 = 0;             //be called from the ACH once. 
            //Used for later constructing of the output file. 

        //GUI stuff below for the input file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TXT & ACH Files", "txt", "ach");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {

            try{                    //Section for the buffer reader/writer. 

                String sCurrentLine;


                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getCurrentDirectory()+"//NachaOutput.ACH")); 
                while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)
                {


                    //Below is conditional statements that check to see if the line contains certain
                    //characters. If they do the it takes the lines and writes them to a new 
                    //document (set above). It also adds +1 to the counter so the same numbers
                    //will not be written twice. 
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);   

                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){

                        count1++;
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.newLine();
                        five = sCurrentLine;





                    }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && count2 == 0){

                        count2++;
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.newLine();

                    }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){

                        count3++;
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.newLine();
                        eight = sCurrentLine;

                    }else if(sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && count2 ==1){

                        bw.write(five);
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.write(eight);



                    }else{

                    }

                }


            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();


            } finally {

                try {

                    if (br != null)br.close();
                    if (bw != null)bw.close();

                }catch (IOException ex){

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Assuming I only have one "6" number in my original file, the program works fine. The problem arises when I have more than one "6", because I have no way (that I am aware of) to repaste the "5" and "8" numbers more than once. My initial plan was to copy the "sCurrentLine" String into two strings called "five" and "eight" that could be easily referenced later and their values entered before and after each of the "6" numbers remaining in the text file as shown below:

```
if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){

                        count1++;
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.newLine();
                        five = sCurrentLine;
```

and

```
}else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){

                        count3++;
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.newLine();
                        eight = sCurrentLine;
```

where I would utilize the values here:

```
}else if(sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && count2 ==1){

                        bw.write(five);
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.write(eight);
```

I get a "nullpointer" error on the line where I try to write the (five) variable which should contain the value of sCurrentLine at the time when I set the "five" variable. (So it should simply post a "5 somtething" number. I have been unable to find a way to make "five" equal to sCurrentLine without generating an error no matter how many ways I tried. I also tried using PrintScreen to check within the method that I set "five" and it did in fact set successfully, so I am totally lost on how to remedy this situation.

I'm hoping someone here can provide me on how to correct this problem.. This is a work assignment, not casual and I am stressed trying to figure it out.

Thanks in advance and let me know if you need more information!

EDIT: My apologizes: here is the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at nacha.Nacha.main(Nacha.java:83)
```

flagging at:

```
bw.write(eight);
```

Comment: When you ask about an exception, ALWAYS post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: So, either `bw` is null, or `eight` is null. `bw` can't be null, otherwise the exception would have been thrown sooner. So the only left option is that `eight` is null.

Comment: So, is your NPE happening when you try to write `five` or when you try to write `eight`?  The main text of your question contradicts the stack trace part of your question.

Comment: In either case, the first thing the `write()` method does is try to find the length of the string you passed in, which will throw an NPE if you pass in a `null`.

Comment: It happens when I try to write eight. I think the reason is because my logic is messed up. I think the way Buffered Reader works when it attempts to read the second "6" the eight value hasn't been set yet since it is at the bottom of the list therefore it is null. Unfortunatly I have no idea how to fix this without scrapping a large amount of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
                if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){

                    count1++;
                    bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                    bw.newLine();
                    five = sCurrentLine;





                }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && count2 == 0){

                    count2++;
                    bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                    bw.newLine();

                }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){

                    count3++;
                    bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                    bw.newLine();
                    eight = sCurrentLine;

                }else if(sCurrentLine.startsWith("6") && count2 ==1){

                    bw.write(five);
                    bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                    bw.write(eight);
                }
```

Notice in the first if statement, you set variable five. 
Five now has a value, so it is not `null`.
You never set eight to a value, therefore, it is still `null`.

The flow of your program following this file:

```
111111111111111111111111
522293884838383848484838483884
62837717273727
62993304993918
621272773727755828
821200303299191
90000000000000000000000000
99999999999999999999999999;
99999999999999999999999999
```

You reach the first if statement first, which sets five to "522293884838383848484838483884"

The second if statement is reached, printing "62837717273727" to file.

The third if statement is not reached, as "62993304993918" begins with 6, not 8.

The fourth if statement is then reached, attempting to write five variable, the current line, and a null eight variable.

I would suggest creating an ArrayList of strings, and for each line starting with 6, add the string to the arraylist. Then, when you've set five and eight, iterating over the arraylist and writing as you see fit.

```
ArrayList <String> sixValues = new ArrayList();

if(sCurrentLine.startsWith("6"){

sixValues.add(sCurrentLine);

}
```

and the for-loop

```
for( String s : sixValues){
                        bw.write(five);
                        bw.write(sCurrentLine);
                        bw.write(eight);
}
```

Comment: The key here is to remember the six values for later, rather than trying to deal with them the moment you get them. 

Instead of stopping halfway through reading the file and outputting a small chunk, we go through the entire file, read the values into slots, then deposit them all in one big chunk.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct Psychrom good advice. I used an "Array List" to store the "6" values and then call them later outside of that first while loop.

Allowed me to solve my problem and complete the project, at least the first part of it. (This is just the high-level portion). Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Not a problem, have a great day! :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Psychrom for helping me to get to this solution, his answer was 100% correct in what I needed to do I wish I could give him some reputation, but I can't.

Here is my final working code FYI:

```
package nacha;

import java.awt.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;



public class Nacha extends JComponent implements Accessible

{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        String five = null;
        String eight = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;
        int count1 = 0;
        int count2 = 0;             //Counter variables for the numbers that should only 
        int count3 = 0;             //be called from the ACH once. 
            //Used for later constructing of the output file. 

        //GUI stuff below for the input file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TXT & ACH Files", "txt", "ach");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {

            try{                    //Section for the buffer reader/writer. 

                String sCurrentLine;


                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getCurrentDirectory()+"//NachaOutput.ACH")); 
                while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)
                {


                    //Below is conditional statements that check to see if the line contains certain
                    //characters. If they do the it takes the lines and writes them to a new 
                    //document (set above). It also adds +1 to the counter so the same numbers
                    //will not be written twice. 

                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){

                        five = sCurrentLine;





                    }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6")){

                        list.add(sCurrentLine);

                    }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){

                        eight = sCurrentLine;


                    }else{

                    }

                }

                while(list.size() > 0){

                String six = null;

                bw.write(five);
                bw.newLine();
                six = list.get(0);
                bw.write(six);
                bw.newLine();
                list.remove(0);
                bw.write(eight);
                bw.newLine();

                }



            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();


            } finally {

                try {



                    if (br != null)br.close();
                    if (bw != null)bw.close();

                }catch (IOException ex){

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

UPDATE:
For anyone who ever looks this up or is interested, I thought I would give an update with my latest progress. This time I had to edit the program so that it could accept a ACH file that may contain multiple 5's or 6's meaning that I need the program to cycle through the first instance of 5 and every 6 followed by the 8, then the next instance of 5 followed by every 6 followed by 8 and so on.

I ended up using a "if statement" inside of a "while" loop inside of a "while" loop. If anyone has a way to do this better or make the code more professional I would love to hear it:

```
package nacha;


import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;




public class Nacha extends JComponent implements Accessible

{


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ArrayList<String> listSix = new ArrayList<String>();    //List used to store the 6 starting numbers.
        ArrayList<String> listFive = new ArrayList<String>();   //List used to store the 5 starting numbers.

        String five = null;                                 //String used to store 5 starting numbers
        String eight = null;                                //String used to store 8 starting numbers.
        BufferedReader br = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;



        //GUI stuff below for the input file
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("ACH Files", "ach");
        chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Please choose ACH file to upload");
        int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(chooser);
        if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
        {

            try{                    

                String sCurrentLine;        //Sets the string for the line the Buffered Reader is currently reading.

                //Below sets the location for the reader/writer actions. 
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chooser.getSelectedFile()));
                bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(chooser.getCurrentDirectory()+"//NachaOutput.ACH")); 
                while((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) !=null)
                {


                    //Below are the conditional statements that check to see if the line begins with a certain 
                    //character then either (1)writes the line to a string (2)writes the line into the array list
                    //or (3)does nothing and "ignores" the line. 

                    if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("5")){

                        listFive.add(sCurrentLine);

                        }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("6")){

                        listSix.add(sCurrentLine);

                    }else if (sCurrentLine.startsWith("8")){

                        eight = sCurrentLine;

                    }else{

                    }

                }

                while(listFive.size() > 0){                 //While there is some value in the "5" list. 

                    five = listFive.get(0);                 //Make the string "five" equal to index 0 of the list. 
                    ArrayList<String> listSixDuplicate = new ArrayList<String>(listSix);        //Creates a duplicate of "six" list to manipulate. 

                    while(listSixDuplicate.size() > 0){             //While there is some value in the "6" list. 

                        bw.write(five);         
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.write(listSixDuplicate.get(0));//    <-------    Writes information in correct format to the outgoing file. 
                        listSixDuplicate.remove(0);
                        bw.newLine();
                        bw.write(eight);
                        bw.newLine();
                        int size = listSixDuplicate.size();         //Creates a variable called "size" that is the size of "six". 
                        if (size == 0)                              //If the size of the list "six" is empty..
                                listFive.remove(0);                 //Remove the value from index "0" of list "five". 
                        //Loops back to beginning to see if list "five" has any more values. 
                        }



                }


                //Lets the user know what the output file is named and where it has been saved. 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Output file saved as NachaOutput.ach to " + chooser.getCurrentDirectory());

                //Below is necessary exception handling for using the buffered reader/writer. 
            }catch (IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();


            } finally {

                try {


                    //Closes the buffer reader/writer. 
                    if (br != null)br.close();
                    if (bw != null)bw.close();

                }catch (IOException ex){

                    ex.printStackTrace();

                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```